# ASP:TextBox or ASP:CheckBoxList, throwing Javascript errors when Requiredfield validator is there

Tags: asp.net, sharepoint

I have created a User Control for my SharePoint, which has a simple `TextBox` and a `CheckBoxList`. For both of these controls, I have `ASP:RequiredFieldValidator` and `ASP:RegularExpressionValidator`.

When I select some item in the `CheckBoxList` or type some input in the `TextBox`, I am getting a javascript error in some unknown location. (This is not accepted by my customer.)

Now, when I debug this using FireBug, in the console I see `validators[i]` is null. It is actually failing in the JS code generated by these validators.

Can some one help me?

**Edited:**

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtNumbers" runat="server" CssClass="Label4" ></asp:TextBox>
                                    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorGPC" runat="server"
                                        ControlToValidate="txtNumbers" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers Accepted "
                                        ValidationExpression="^\d+$"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredNUMValue" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumbers"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

Also, 
I added required field validators for `RadioButtonList` (not `CheckBoxList`).

```
<asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtOptions" runat="server" CssClass="Label3">
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" />
                                        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" />
                                    </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rbtOptions"
                                        SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please Select a Valid Option"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```

When I either input any text in the `TextBox` or select any option, there is a JavaScript error.

Comment: Can you please provide a snippet of the markup (Of the 2 controls and their validators)? That will make it a bit easier for people to help.

Comment: Are you saying that you have tried to put a RequiredFieldValidator for a CheckboxList? That is not possible (it won't work).

Answer (score 0):

There is something else on your page that is conflicting with this. Taking what you posted and trying a simple page it works as it should, so I'm assuming that there's other elements / scripts that are causing this.

```
<div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNumbers" runat="server" CssClass="Label4"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="RegularExpressionValidatorGPC" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumbers" ErrorMessage="Only Numbers Accepted " ValidationExpression="^\d+$" SetFocusOnError="true"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredNUMValue" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtNumbers" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please enter a valid number"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rbtOptions" runat="server" CssClass="Label3">
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 1" />
        <asp:ListItem Text="Option 2" />
    </asp:RadioButtonList>
    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="rbtOptions" SetFocusOnError="true" ErrorMessage="Please Select a Valid Option"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="submit" />
</div>
```

Do you have any script tags, or other elements in your markup that could be interfering with this?

Self closed  tags can cause issues like this ( is a no no)